# How to create network traffic router with docker and kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I need to create an architecture for network router. I want to have a simple app (in docker), that listens for packets (from the Internet) with given source_id and routes its further to the Internet. That means, each running instance will be processing packets from one source.

Managing the instances will be done with external tools (user defines the routing table).

Scaling is not required, since every instance will process around 1Mbps, but there might be up to 100 000 instances (routing entries).

**Question: Is kubernetes right tool for this?** Target is Google Cloud. Maybe I should use other orchiestriation system, **or use bare docker**?

I think kubernetes' Statefulset might be the answer, but I'm not sure.